# Any $f \in C^0([0,1])$ can be approximated arbitrarily well in a sup norm sense by a $C^1([0,1])$ function

Tags: real-analysis

I think this is a very interesting question and I would like to solve it without invoking the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem and using elementary methods. Here is my attempt to solve this question:

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. We would like to show that for any $f \in C^0([0,1])$, there exists a $g \in C^1([0,1])$: $$\|g - f\|_{\infty} < \epsilon.$$

Let $f \in C^0([0,1])$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous so there exists a $\delta > 0:$ $$|x-y| < \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x) - f(y) | < \epsilon.$$ Set $h = \delta/2$ and define the extension of $f$ to be $\tilde{f} : [-h,1+h] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$\tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases} f(0) & x \in [-h,0) \\
f(x) & x \in [0,1] \\
f(1) & x \in (1,h].\end{cases}$$ Define $F : [-h,1+h] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$F(x) = \int_0^x \tilde{f}(t)dt.$$ Observe that $F$ is continuous and $F' = \tilde{f}$ on $[-h,1+h]$. Also, we have that $$F(x+h) - F(x-h) = \int_{x-h}^{x+h} \tilde{f}(t)dt.$$ Finally, set $$g(x) = \frac{F(x+h)-F(x-h)}{2h} = \frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} \tilde{f}(t)dt.$$ Observe that $g \in C^1([0,1])$ as $F$ is differentiable and its derivative $\tilde{f}$ is continuous. Consider any interval $[x-h,x+h]$. By the mean value theorem, there exists a $c \in (x-h,x+h)$: $$F'(c) = \tilde{f}(c) = \frac{F(x+h) - F(x-h)}{2h} = g(x).$$ Then for any $x \in [0,1]$, we have that$$|c - x| < 2h = \delta \Longrightarrow |\tilde{f}(c) - f(x)| < \epsilon \Longrightarrow |g(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon.$$ Since this holds for any $x \in [0,1]$, we conclude that $$\|g - f\|_{\infty} < \epsilon.$$ I would like to try to improve on this proof if possible because I feel like it can be simplified or there could be errors in my construction. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Let $f_n = f \ast h_n$ where $h_n(x)= n (1 -\cos(2\pi n x))1_{|x| < 1/2n}$ and $\ast $ is the convolution. Also [choosing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $h_n \in C^\infty_c$ you get $f_n \in C^\infty_c$

Answer (score 0):

I have not studied your work. But here is a suggestion for a proof:

Every $f\in C^0[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous. So for $\epsilon >0$ take $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall x,y\in [0,1] \;(|x-y|<\frac {1}{n}\implies |f(x)-f(y)<\epsilon). $

Take $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that  $g(\frac {j}{n})=f(\frac {j}{n})$ for $j\in \{0,1,..., n\} $ and such that     $g$ is linear on  $\left[\frac {j}{n},\frac {j+1}{n}\right]$ for each $j\in \{0,..., n-1\}.$

Now "round off" the "corners" of the graph of $g.$  That is, for $1\leq j\leq n-1 ,$ we can find $a_j$ and $b_j$ in $0,1)$ with $\frac {j-1}{n}<a_j<\frac {j}{n}<b_j<\frac {j+1}{n},$ with also $b_{j-1}<a_j$ for $j\geq 2$,.... such that there exist   quadratics $q_j(x)$ satisfying $$\forall x\in [a_j,b_j]\;( |q_j(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$$  $$\text {and }\quad q_j'(a_j)=g'(a_j) \quad \text {and  } \quad q_j'(b_j)=g'(b_j).$$ Now let $h(x)=q_j(x)$ for  $x\in [a_j,b_j]$ and let $h(x)=g(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]\backslash \cup_{j=1}^{n-1}[a_j,b_j].$